# Xamarin.Forms, Set MaxLines in editor

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an editor:

```
                            <Editor
                                 Margin="10,0,10,10"
                                 x:Name="entry_descri_pickcate" 
                                 FontFamily="arial"
                                 MaxLength="190"                                  
                                 FontSize="14"
                                 TextColor="#dfdfdf"
                                 BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                                 PlaceholderColor="#dfdfdf"
                                 Placeholder="Beschreibung ..." 
                                  />
```

This editor has a max length property but not a max lines property. This causes anyone to destroy our layout. It is not our goal do disable line breaks, but at some point a new line must be forbidden.

How do I achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The MaxLines property for now is not supported. But it would be reported on GitHub.
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10689

This feature has be added to Enhancement. Please follow the progress.